# clojure/lein REPL with jline

Tags: clojure, jline

For some reason I can't get clojure REPL working with jline, what i did was git clone the clojure repository off github then run ant to build it, then i download jline-0.9.94.jar to the directory with clojure.jar, then run the following command:

```
java -cp jline-0.9.94.jar:clojure.jar jline.ConsoleRunner clojure.main
```

And get the following errors:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.main
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:375)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
 at jline.ConsoleRunner.main(Unknown Source)
```

Here are the files in my current directory:

```
vvshs-macbook-2:clojure vvsh$ ls
build.xml                                 clojure-sources-1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT.jar epl-v10.html                              src
classes                                   clojure-sources.jar                       jline-0.9.94.jar                          test
clojure-1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT.jar         clojure.iml                               pom-template.xml
clojure-slim-1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT.jar    clojure.jar                               pom.xml
clojure-slim.jar                          doc                                       readme.txt
vvshs-macbook-2:clojure vvsh$
```

I got the same error on clojure 1.1 and lein repl(it seems lein maintain its own version of clojure).

By the way, this is on mac ox 10.5.8

```
java version "1.5.0_24"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_24-b02-357-9M3165)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_24-149, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Anybody know what's wrong and how to fix it? As I really want to get lein repl working to start a project.

Comment: Actually this setup works for me in almost identical environment (OSX, Clojure from source, jline, same command line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the same problem today by removing a redundant `jline*.jar` from `/Library/Java/Extensions`, leaving just one jline installation in `CLASSPATH`.

**Longer explanation:** I was trying to build [labrepl](http://github.com/relevance/labrepl), which installs all its dependencies in subdirectory `lib`, but I had previously set up jline by copying the .jar file to `/Library/Java/Extensions`. [Apparently](http://markmail.org/message/ofr3dp4mqkdlixju), `java.lang.ClassLoader` couldn't handle two installations of jline, and as long as there were ones available in two places, the command line starting a Clojure REPL would fail finding the latter one of classes `jline.ConsoleRunner` and `clojure.main`, depending on the order they were given to the `java` command.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, everything works now,  i can't believe simple remove it solve the problem.

Comment: I got hit by that as well. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655852/why-is-my-javap-output-different-than-yours-for-the-same-jar-file/5530443#5530443) for another version of the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

see my alternative instructions for install on my fork:

http://github.com/jedschneider/leiningen

I sent a pull request to update the readme, but didn't get a response on it. once you have lein installed, you can put the bin/leiningen.sh in your ~/bin and call it anywhere. i put a shortcut on my .bash_profile

`alias lein="~/bin/leiningen.sh"`

and then call `lein repl` to launch a shell

also checkout the labrepl which is a great learning tool.

http://github.com/relevance/labrepl

Comment: Thanks for the good tool, I got the lein repl working by using pyrtsa's method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `java ...` command looks fine, I'd double check if all the jars are where you think they should be (and that they are *the* jars you think they are, i.e. `clojure.jar` is actually the one you built locally and not some super-outdated one).

If you want to use Leiningen for `lein repl`, that's possible too. Note that it isn't accurate to say that it "maintains its own version of Clojure"; Leiningen is a build tool, used as part of a project-oriented workflow, and the separate Clojure jars are project-specific. To create a sample project to play around in, say `lein new foo` someplace convenient. Then you'll need to `cd foo`, get your Clojure & contrib jars with `lein deps` (the `project.clj` skeleton provided by `lein new` already contains entries for both) and start a REPL with `lein repl`.

Finally, you could use the new [`cljr` project](http://github.com/liebke/cljr); it has a comprehensive README which should get you started in no time, and with it you'll be able to say `cljr repl` to get a Clojure REPL anywhere, without the need to create a "project".

Comment: Ah, by the way, if you want a fresh build of Clojure, you might be better off going to http://build.clojure.org/ and getting a jar from there. And if you're starting with the language -- it's not apparent from the question whether you are or not, but if -- you should probably stick with 1.1.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner so I think all the features in 1.1 will be enough to learn:)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. jline.ConsoleRunner (at least about jline-0.9.5 which I use) seems not to be able to find class files in the path added to class search paths from -cp option of 'java' command. It means it can't find neither classes in your current directory.  I solved this by copying clojure.main under /Library/Java/Extensions/ too.